# select menu grows bigger when placed inside the table in JQuery Mobile with mulipleselect option

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using a Select menu with Multiple select option and placed inside a td of a table row. Each time when the more items are selected from the select menu and when the select menu can not accommodate the selected items' names instead of truncating the text the select menu grows bigger in size. The problem does not arise when the control is placed inside just a div container instead of a table td.

```
 <table  style="width: 100%;top:50%">
 <tr > 
 <td  nowrap><label id="lblUserName" class=ui-label-criteria>Length:</label></td>
  <td width=50px> 
      <select name="select-choice-4" id="idLength" multiple="multiple data-native-menu="true" class=ui-field-criteria">
        <option value="standard">Standard: 7 day</option>
        <option value="rush">Rush: 3 days</option>
        <option value="express">Express: next day</option>
        <option value="overnight">Overnight</option>
        <option>Choose options</option>
        </select>
    </td>
  </tr>

 </table >
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use the style attribute `overflow: hidden` on the select box?